# Analyse variation between distribution curves according to factors

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mixed-model, curve-fitting, functional-data-analysis

I have a set of continuous distributions representing the leaf area density found at different heights through a forest canopy. e.g. like that found in [Whitehurst et al. (2013)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/258811403_Characterization_of_Canopy_Layering_in_Forested_Ecosystems_Using_Full_Waveform_Lidar):

[image]

For each of these foliage density profiles I also have information on the tree species diversity and tree trunk diameter of each tree contributing to the leaf area found in these profiles.

**What statistical techniques can I use to test whether these foliage density profiles vary meaningfully as a result of various metrics related to tree diversity such as number of tree species, variance of trunk diameter?**

Comment: One useful thing to do is to visually inspect a 3D scatterplot of the data from different viewing angles and see if any pattern seems obvious. Do you have access to software capable of 3D scatterplotting and 3D surface (z=f(x,y) modeling?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for *functional data analysis*, which is the branch of statistics where "observations" are entire curves, which are then modeled in various ways. There are a couple of textbooks cited in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_data_analysis). We also have a tag [functional-data-analysis](/questions/tagged/functional-data-analysis).